#  sizeof() of a nested structure array

Tags: c

**EDITED**

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct ns{
 int sd;
 int we;
 char st;
 int m;
}ds;
typedef struct numb
{
  char b;
  ds rt;
}num;
static num a[]={1,'a'};
int read(int number)
{
 printf("%d\n",number);
 return 1;
}
int main()
{
    printf("%d",sizeof(a[0].rt));
    read(sizeof(a[0].rt));
    read(sizeof(a[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

My doubt is sizeof of an array when passed as a parameter will be modified as a temporary pointer variable. But here in array of structures as well as in the array of nested structure when trying to print the sizeof it gives the actual size. why the second read which contains array of structures is not getting converted to pointers as its an array.

Comment: Nope, the size comes out right. You just have to adjust your expectations.

Comment: What do you mean *output size to large*?

Comment: What size do you expect to be printed? What result are you getting? What is your platform?

Comment: It's hard to tell with such abbreviated names for your variables, but `static rat a[]={1,'a'};` looks wrong. You're not initializing the `rt` member of your `struct`, and you're only giving one element in your `a` array. Perhaps this is what you intended, but as I said, it's hard to tell with names like `ds`, `rat`, and `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear.

Anyway, firstly, when arrays are implicitly converted to pointers, it is the standard *array-to-pointer conversion* that's responsible for that. *Array-to-pointer conversion* is implicitly applied in some contexts, but not in all contexts. For example, *array-to-pointer conversion* is not applied to the operands of `sizeof`, which is why `sizeof` (when used with an array), correctly evaluates to array size (not to pointer size).

Secondly, `a[0]` is not an array. `a` is an array. `a[0]` is a `num` object, which is not an array at all. So, why you expect `a[0]` to be converted to a pointer is totally not clear to me.

Comment: Thanks andrey. My doubt is whether an array to pointer conversion takes place when calculating sizeof an array passed as parameter.

Comment: @Angus: It depends on what you mean by "array passed as parameter". There are different ways to pass an array as a parameter. In any case, in your code sample there's no arrays passed as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into an optimization most 32-bit and 64-bit compilers will perform to align the items in the struct. Generally each element will be padded out to the system WORD size (probably 32 or 64-bits on a desktop, 8/16 possible on embedded mcu). This is so systems don't have to deal with pointers to non-aligned data, which are usually extra work for the system to access.

You can generally force the compiler to "pack" your structures so they will only use the minimum amount of space, but you are basically trading a few bytes of RAM for a few extra bytes of code space and possibly slightly slower execution. This may make sense on a RAM limited system or when dealing with serializing data for a communication protocol.

Also note that method to pack a struct varies wildly from one compiler to the next, so don't expect it to compile everywhere without some hefty macro work.

In GCC, the way to "pack" a struct is like such:

```
typedef struct  __attribute__ ((__packed__))
{
   int a;
   char b;
   long long c;
   short d;
} PackedStruct;
```